# Learn HazelCast Fundamentals

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I wanted to learn Hazelcast. Can someone please suggest me any good site or video to start with.
We wanted to use Hazelcast caching and locks with are .net applications

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good resources:

- [Hazelcast Getting Started](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/get-started/)
- [Hazelcast .Net Client Documentation](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client)
- [Hazelcast .Net Client Feature List](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/clients-languages/dotnet/)
- [Hazelcast Complete Documentation (Reference Manual)](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the resources I can recommend below. Hazelcast Training Center has very useful courses.

- https://hazelcast.org/imdg/get-started/
- https://training.hazelcast.com/hazelcast-imdg-overview
- https://training.hazelcast.com/imap-course
- https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client/tree/v3.12.3#748-using-lock